# PHPUnit gives No Code Coverage Driver Is Available

Tags: xdebug, pcov

I have a laravel project and I tried to run `phpunit` to give me a coverage report.  I ran the command `vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html storage/test-output-data/coverage-html` and it gave the output:

```
PHPUnit 8.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Error:         No code coverage driver is available
```

I tried to resolve this situation by doing a `sudo pecl install pcov`, but running the phpunit still gave the same error above.

I noticed that I have the file `/usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so`.  So I added the line `extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so` to my `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` file.  But when I type `php -v`, I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/lib/php/20190902//usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902//usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.11 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2020 19:44:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I also have a folder called `/usr/lib/php/20190902` but it does not have a `pcov.so` file.

I also tried doing a `sudo pecl install xdebug`, but I run into similar errors as above where phpunit says there's no driver and typing `php -v` says some global variable is missing similar to the pcov issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `/usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so` -- this is for PHP **v7.2** (based on `20170718` part) while you are trying to use it in **PHP 7.4**. Yeah -- just get the right version of Xdebug or PCOV for your PHP 7.4 (P.S. for PHP 7.4 the API version will be `20190902`)

Comment: Try this solution to "switch" / install extensions via PECL for specific PHP version (7.4 instead of your current 7.2): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54594604/783119

Comment: @lazyone thank you, doing a `sudo pecl -d php_suffix=7.4 install pcov` properly installed pcov for me.  And now PHPUnit is able to generate the coverage reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I noticed that I have the file `/usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so`. So I added the line `extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so` to my `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` file.

This file is for **PHP 7.2** (based on `20170718` part) while you are trying to use it in PHP **7.4**.

You need to get the right version of Xdebug (or PCOV) for your PHP 7.4. (*NOTE: for PHP 7.4 the API version (and the right folder in the path) will be `20190902`.*)

Try this solution from the following answer to switch / install extensions via PECL for specific PHP version (7.4 instead of your current 7.2): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54594604/783119

```
sudo pecl -d php_suffix=7.4 install <package-name>
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with PHPUnit. You have a problem with your PHP environment: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/lib/php/20190902//usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902//usr/lib/php/20170718/pcov.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install xdebug, so the coverage knows how to run.

For example, for PHP 7.1, it's this package:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-xdebug
```

Just fixed it today for my scenario. In your case, just change the PHP version to:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-xdebug
```