# Fail pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

Tags: php, docker, centos, xdebug, pecl

My develop environment

```
CentOS: 7.9 (Using FROM centos:7.9.2009 From DockerHub)
PHP: 7.4.33
Apache: 2.4.55
```

I'm trying to create Docker container by using Dockerfile. With the above  environment, I tried to install Xdebug:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.6
```

But received message

> No releases available for package "example.net/xdebug" install failed.

On internet, they said I need to update pecl with this command:

```
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
```

But it failed and I received the following error message:

[image]

I can't understand that suggestion `Trying channel "example.net" over https:// instead`.
Should I put some options to use `https://`? Is there such an option?

I really tired to search the solution about this, there's no solution.
Someone who experienced that error, please give me some advice to solve... Thanks.

Comment: Could you please check it - https://matthewsetter.com/setup-step-debugging-php-xdebug3-docker/

Comment: Fro whatever reason, your system/OS reports **PHP v5.4.16** and not 7.4.33. Xdebug 3.1 requires PHP 7.2+, it's not available for 5.4.

Comment: Check the following that may help with telling pecl that you have the right PHP version: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385508/phpunit-gives-no-code-coverage-driver-is-available/64391564#64391564 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594530/pecl-install-xdebug-fails-because-it-finds-built-in-older-php-instead-of-homebre/54594604#54594604

Comment: @Dmitry thank you for suggestion. I'll check the webpage.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you for comment. First, I put wrong screenshot, sorry. I put img again.
I'm not sure, but Without login my Docker container, 
"pecl install xdebug-3.1.6 " fails because of version of PHP. 
But as img shows, I installed correct verstion of PHP...

After login Docker container, 
"pecl install xdebug-3.1.6 " failed because of  No releases available for package.
And "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" failed because of "Channel "pecl.php.net" is not responding over http://". thanks.

Comment: Sadly I cannot help with the issue on the new screenshot. No ideas on this one.