# PECL fails to install Xdebug on PHP 8.1 because it thinks I'm on PHP version 7.4

Tags: php, macos, xdebug, pecl

I've searched far and wide, tried everything but I can't get to install Xdebug on PHP 8.1

I've got multiple PHP versions installed via homebrew, when I switch to PHP 8.1 and try to install Xdebug I get the following:

```
BE-C02CRC3FMD6N:~ treynaert$ php -v
PHP 8.1.14 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2023 16:02:41) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.14, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

BE-C02CRC3FMD6N:~ treynaert$ pecl install xdebug
pecl/xdebug requires PHP (version >= 8.0.0, version <= 8.2.99), installed version is 7.4.33
No valid packages found
install failed
```

As you can see, `php -v` returns 8.1, `phpinfo()` in the browser gives me the same. Though for some reason pecl thinks I'm on 7.4.

I'm on Mac OSX Catalina BTW (10.15.7)

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: In addition to switching to the 8.1 binary for `php`, you also need to switch to 8.1 for `phpize` and `php-config`. Not sure how to do that in OSX/Homebrew. (In Ubuntu, you'd likely do it via `update-alternatives`.)

Comment: php-config --version  ==> 8.1.14
So that seems fine as well

Comment: Will making config/calling pecl like this do any good? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54594604/783119

Comment: nope, found that answer as well and tried but no success

Comment: What do `which pecl` and `which php` show? (Or the OSX equivalent if `which` doesn't exist)